# Docusign PHP sdk set Recipient Signature Provider

Tags: docusignapi

I have the the following JSON to create envelope with EU Advanced authentication.

```
 [{
                            "signatureProviderName": "universalsignaturepen_opentrust_hash_tsp",
                            "signatureProviderOptions": {
                                "sms": "+*********"
                            }
                        }]
```

I cant find an example / documentation on how to do similar when using the DocuSign PHP SDK.

think along these lines:

```
 $recipient_signature_providers = \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientSignatureProvider( [{
                            "signatureProviderName": "universalsignaturepen_opentrust_hash_tsp",
                            "signatureProviderOptions": {
                                "sms": "+******"
                            }
                        }]);
```

Comment: Answered below. If it helped you out, be sure to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. There's are two classes specific to RecipientSignatureProviders in the SDK.

You'll want to use the [models/RecipientSignatureProvider](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/e42e98d48f8c5c8280679f05cebd32929d7cf380/src/Model/RecipientSignatureProvider.php) and [models/RecipientSignatureProviderOptions](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/e42e98d48f8c5c8280679f05cebd32929d7cf380/src/Model/RecipientSignatureProviderOptions.php):

```
$options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientSignatureProviderOptions([
  'sms' => '*******']);

$recipient_signature_provider = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientSignatureProvider([ 
    'signature_provider_name' => 'universalsignaturepen_opentrust_hash_tsp',
    'signature_provider_options' => $options
]);
```

Comment: Many Thanks and to Assign it to Signer::$options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientSignatureProviderOptions([
  'sms' => '+*******']);

$recipient_signature_provider = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientSignatureProvider([ 
    'signature_provider_name' => 'universalsignaturepen_opentrust_hash_tsp',
    'signature_provider_options' => $options
]);

 $signer= new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([

'name' => $recipientName,

'email' => $recipientEmail,

'recipient_id' => "1", 

'tabs' => $tabs
]);
$signer->setRecipientSignatureProviders($recipient_signature_provider);

Comment: to attach to the signer is: $signer->setRecipientSignatureProviders([$recipient_signature_provider]);